# how to push webservice code to github

Tags: github

I have a project that has a webservice for send sms.
when I add the WSDL address in my project some files add to my project that include some code.
when I add my project to github all file added except the file that web service  add to my project.
why?

Comment: Are you sure you added it to your commit?

Comment: As @Mureinik mentioned, you have to be sure your changes got committed. Maybe the directory containing the files is in the `.gitignore`.

Comment: I commit ahh file togehter.